# aws emr can't change default pyspark python on bootstrap

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using aws with emr, and trying to change to bootstrap script in order to set the default python in pyspark to be python 3, I am following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/) tutorial

this is changing the /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh file, but does not change the python version in pyspark, I am still getting jobs done with python 2.7. this is only working when I ssh to the machine and specifically use

```
$source /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.ssh
```

When I try to add this line to the bootstrap script I am getting bootstrap error that the file is not found.

> /bin/bash: /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh: No such file or directory

I assume that the file does not exist in this stage. How can I set the pyspark python to be python 3 in the bootstrap script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code to software configuration (create emr -> step1: software and steps -> edit software configuration -> enter configuration)

```
[
  {
     "Classification": "spark-env",
     "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
            "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
          }
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It doesnt works as it is being ignored "Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property:"

Comment: @A.B, did you try to put this configuration in the AWS UI? (not by command line)

Comment: While the command line supports configurations, this does not work when provisioning a cluster from the aws cli.  It does work when performed in the UI.  The fact that there is a difference is frustrating.